# cURL error when inserting records to azure table storage using Azure SDK for PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm getting this error while inserting records from a file to Azure Table Storage  using the Azure SDK for PHP. I'm reading thousands of lines and insert them one by one using batch operation but in the middle of the operation, an error is encountered. This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 
'cURL error 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), 
errno 0 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\root\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\root\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\root\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\root in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
```

Is there a solution for this one?

Comment: I updated the stack trace to make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide your key code snippet of generate the batching operation? As according the limitation described at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#storage-limits,

> **Target throughput for single table partition (1 KB entities) Up to 2000 entities per second**.

You can try to divide your entities into several batchs with several PartitionKeys.

As the example of batch operations at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/samples/TableSamples.php#L84, you can try to reduce the number of entities in a single insert batch operation.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.